# php autoloader Fatal error: Class not found

Tags: php, namespaces

I am using PHP ActiveRecord with my small MVC framework thtat includes an autoloader. In my controller I access the model Pub::find(64) for example.

My problem is that Pub::find(64) is inheritating the namespace of the controller and I get the error

```
Fatal error: Class 'App\Controllers\Pub' not found in /home/i554246/public_html/mvc/App/Controllers/Index.php on line 27
```

Pub is the Module name. The file get included ok. I can solve this issue by appending \Pub::find(64) but this is not really intuitive for new people on the project.

Is there a way to stop the namespace appending for the Pub::find(64) without altering that line?

Index Controller

```
namespace App\Controllers;

class Index extends \Core\Controller
{
    protected
        $title = 'Home'
        ;

    /**
     * Default action
     */
    public function index()
    {
        // Pass the data to the view to display it
        $this->view->set('testdb', \Pub::find(64));

    }
}
```

App.php

```
/**
 * Class autoloader
 * @param $className
 * @see https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-0.md
 */
public function autoload($className)
{
    preg_match('/(^.+\\\)?([^\\\]+)$/', ltrim($className, '\\'), $match);

    //Build namespace Autoloading
    $file = str_replace('\\', '/', $match[1]) . str_replace('_', '/', $match[2]) . '.php';

    //Build Model path
    $model = 'App/Models/' . $match[2] . '.php';

    if ( is_file($file) ) {
        require $file;
    }elseif ( is_file($model) ) {
        require $model;
    }

}
```

Models/Pub.php

```
class Pub extends ActiveRecord\Model
{
}
```

Comment: What is your PHP version? Here, it (correctly, as I haven't made the `Pub` class) says _"Fatal error: Class 'Pub' not found"_ if I use your Index, as `\Pub` is a fully-qualified name.  _However_, it wouldn't be the first time that a framework _'optimizes'_ code by loading all kinds of class declarations in one long 'cache' file and includes that instead of your actual code. Does `PHP ActiveRecord` do this? What does `get_included_files()` say right before that `\Pub` call? What does it say right _after_ you use another (working) Model?

Comment: PHP version 5.3.10, no the framework is mine own very small with just the autoloader. I am now adding modules and I am using PHP ActiveRecord

Comment: Hm ,exactly the same as mine (Debian `PHP 5.3.10-2 (cli) (built: Feb 20 2012 21:36:46)`), I am afraid I am out of ideas then, I hope someone else may shed some light on it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't understand namespaces.

Since you are using namespace `App\Controllers`, the global namespace is denoted with `\`.
So if you don't want to use fully-qualified name `\Pub` you have to put use declaration below the namespace, eg:

```
namespace App\Controllers;
use Pub;
```

PS: It's a good practice to put your models in a namespace too.